# Enable cross site access in OK Hosting?

Tags: iis, fonts, hosting, cross-site

I'm trying to download the bootsrap fonts from a container I have in a site hosted by OK Hosting. I can download the font manually but when using it in a CSS on a page hosted in another server, it fails because cross site access is disabled.

I know OK Hosting uses IIS but they give you a web based control panel.

How do I enable cross site access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you just have to add a file called web.config at the root of your site with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also need the following just below the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
```